# How to do simple type cast in Scala?

Tags: scala, types, casting

This should be a silly question.

```
scala> val aFloat = 1.5f
aFloat: Float = 1.5
```

How to cast aFloat to an Int in a simple way?

I already know to use `a.asInstanceOf[Int]`. But it needs too much keystrokes.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
1.5f.toInt

//--> res0: Int = 1
```

You have toDouble, toFloat, toInt and toLong on all number types.

Answer (score 13):

as well as the toFloat, toInt, etc. methods, you can also use type ascription in some cases:

```
val b = 23 : Byte
```